# Generate a stocklist: create a list using values of nested dictionaries within a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, syntax

I get an api call response as a list containing nested dictionaries. I want to put all the ticker names in to one single list as shown below. What is a way that'll allow me to do that?

Here is the list of the api response:

```
[ {'ticker': 'VOD-22', 'exchange': 'NYSE', 'assetType': 'Stock', 'priceCurrency': 'USD', 
'startDate': '', 'endDate': ''}, {'ticker': 'VOD-23', 'exchange': 'NYSE', 'assetType': 
'Stock', 'priceCurrency': 'USD', 'startDate': '', 'endDate': ''}]
```

I want to turn it into a list with all ticker names, like the following:

```
[ 'VOD-22',  'VOD-23']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a list comprehension

```
ticker_names = [stock['ticker'] for stock in data]
```

where `data` is the json you received from your api call